# dynamically show text box based on dynamically created dropdown menue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new in jsp, and jquery
my code create dynamic text boxes and one drop-down menu based on button clicked,

after created textboxes I want to add one more textbox if the user select option male after the text boxes dynamically added.

the add code works, but the text box when selecting the male option not works.

please please help.

this is my code

```
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <h3 align="center">Change Control Board (CCB)</h3>
        <br />
        <h4 align="center">Enter Change Details</h4>
        <br />
        <form name="form1" method="GET" action="jsv" id="form1">
            <div class="table-repsonsive">
                <span id="error"></span>
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Enter Change Name</th>
                        <th>Enter Change Description</th>
                        <th>Enter Change GW</th>
                        <th>Enter Change AW</th>
                        <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr> name="change_name1[]"';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="change_name[]" class="form-control change_name" /></td>';
            html += '<td><textarea name="change_desc[]" class="form-control change_desc rows="3"" /></td>';
            html += '<td><input  type="text" name="change_GW[]" class="form-control change_GW" /></td>';
            html += '<td><input style="display:none;" id="business"  type="text" name="change_G[]" class="form-control change_GW" /></td>';

            html += '<td><select id="purpose" name="sex-type" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="0">select</option><option value="1">male</option><option value="2">Passing on to a client</option></select></td>';

            html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
            $('#item_table').append(html);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
            if (this.value == '1') {
                $("#business").show();
            } else {
                $("#business").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: just updated answer please check @Alaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have an error on the first line where you are concatenating the tr in the `$html`, it is `'<tr> name="change_name1[]"';` where as it should be `'<tr  name="change_name1[]">';` but since the `name` attribute is not a valid `attribute` for `tr` you should change it to a unique `id`.

I hope the select menu and the input boxes that are generated by the click of a button are not multiple as there is an `id` attribute on the select input which needs to be unique in case there are multiple select boxes, but since it is not mentioned you make a slight change to your event binding like the code below 
You must change the `id`  attributes from static to dynamic something like appending a count along with their ids i have added it for you hope it solves your problem.

your final script will look like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr>';
            html +='<td><input type="text" name="change_name[]" class="form-control change_name" /></td>';
            html +='<td><textarea name="change_desc[]" class="form-control change_desc rows="3"" /></td>';
            html +='<td><input  type="text" name="change_GW[]" class="form-control change_GW" /></td>';
            html += '<td><input style="display:none;" id="business_' + count +
                '"  type="text" name="change_G[]" class="form-control change_GW" /></td>';

            html += '<td><select id="purpose_' + count +
                '" name="sex-type" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="0">select</option><option value="1">male</option><option value="2">Passing on to a client</option></select></td>';

            html +=
                '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
            $('#item_table').append(html);

            $('#purpose_' + count).on('change', function () {
                if (this.value == '1') {
                    $("#business_"+count).show();
                } else {
                    $("#business_"+count).hide();
                }

            });
            count++;
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });


    });
```

Comment: there are multiple select boxes, how can i make the id unique, so the change can be done in every row not only the first one?

Comment: I am sorry i am so bad in that, but the code after select male does not work now

Comment: did you copied the latest code ? @Alaa i just reconfirmed it should work

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now, i copy it before the last change, thank you thank youuu

Comment: you are welcome , donot forget to mark the answer as correct one :) @Alaa

Comment: you have error in code please add underscore id="purpose' + count +

Comment: yeah the `_` was missing thanks for that @ChandrakantThakkar

Answer (score 0):

Cut this code:

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == '1')
    {
       $("#business").show();
    }
         else
    {
       $("#business").hide();
   }
}
```

and paste it right behind  `$('#item_table').append(html);`

Two $(document).ready() sections make no sense. And the event handler (on click) needs to be attached *after* you create the select box.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, now it is work for the first one added, not for all

Answer (score 0):

You are adding select dynamically at run time.so, after adding Select You need to bind it's change event.
So Just make change into your javascript code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    counter=0;
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
      counter=counter+1;
      var html = '';
     html += '<tr> name="change_name1[]"';
     html += '<td><input type="text" name="change_name[]" class="form-control change_name" /></td>';
     html += '<td><textarea name="change_desc[]" class="form-control change_desc rows="3"" /></td>';
     html += '<td><input  type="text" name="change_GW[]" class="form-control change_GW" /></td>';
     html += '<td><input style="display:none;" id="business_'+counter+'"  type="text" name="change_G[]" class="form-control change_GW" /></td>';

    html += '<td><select id="purpose_'+counter+'" name="sex-type" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="0">select</option><option value="1">male</option><option value="2">Passing on to a client</option></select></td>';

     html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
    $('#item_table').append(html);
    $('#purpose_'+counter).on('change', function() {
         if ( this.value == '1')
          {
            $("#business_"+counter).show();
          }
         else
        {
          $("#business_"+counter).hide();
         }

        });
    });




        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

        });


    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, now it works for the first one added, not for all

Comment: @Alaa That's its normal behaviour. You are creating multiple elements with the same id, which is not permitted by the HTML specification. Give each select a different id.

Comment: @Alla you need to give dynamic Id because you are creating multiple elements with same id so only it's work for only first not for all.So create dynamic Id also

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: @Alaa please  check now